# Accessing outerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an HTML DOM element from an IFRAME. I'm trying to get the contents of that IFRAME, but whenever I get the `outerHTML`, it is some truncated version.

Here is an example of the code:

```
var htmlElm = frame.contents().children()[0];
console.log(htmlElm);  //inspect this, i see the outerHTML as i would expect
console.log(htmlElm.outerHTML); //not what was in the chrome inspector,
                                //i get a truncated version
```

Here is an example of HTML that gets truncated, at least for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="https://example.com/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
       window.alert('test');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Body</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It probably just changed since you printed it out, the outerhtml will print as static text while the node will be live.

Comment: that makes sense, except the static text is the truncated version and the live one is the nontruncated version. that seems backwards from what is happening.